# Smarty support for the luna version of eclipse

Tags: eclipse, smarty

Does anyone know how to get smarty / .tpl file support & syntax highlighting in the newest version of eclipse?  smartypdt doesn't seem to be compatible with the most recent version:

https://code.google.com/p/smartypdt/downloads/list - seems like the latest download available is for Juno version.

Any ideas?  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have installed successfully smarty support in Luna, through the [PDT extensions](http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/) site.

Go to Help -> install New Software -> Add http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org and select smartypdt.

See https://code.google.com/p/smartypdt/wiki/InstallSmartyPDT and look at the bottom, the 3 next-to-last comments for more information.